# Is for Node.js similar package where I can print console.log based on deploy environments?

Tags: node.js

In C/C++ I can define macro DEBUG for example and in code I can write

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout<<"Some log data for debugging\n";
#endif
```

and this is printed only if DEBUG macro is defined, for production is undefined and no time lost on printing.
Is for Node.js similar package where I can print `console.log` based on deploy environments ?
Or how to achieve this in Node.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

When you're in development launch Node with `NODE_ENV=development node app.js`

Likewise, set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` when in production.

Then in your code you can do this.

```
var DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV==='development';

if(DEV) console.log('Some log data for debugging');
```